# Redirecting subdomain of one domain, to another domain, without changing the URL (masking)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, virtualhost

I'm really stuck trying to get some mod_rewrite rules working on Apache.

I have a WordPress site on **example.com** and would like **pay.example.com** to redirect and serve **newdomain.com** without losing the original URL, **example.com**

Both domains are on the same server, pointing to the same domain.

We have tried modifying our mod_rewrite/.htaccess configuration several times:

Original WP .htaccess: (we added our lines after this)
https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/

Additionally, we added these lines to try and create the redirect/URL masking:

**First:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pay.example.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [P]
```

**Second:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pay\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

**And as a last resort:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pay.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://newdomain.com/$1 [L, R=301]
```

We also tried placing these at the top of the file, right after RewriteEngine On ...

Ideally, this is what we are trying to achieve:

When someone clicks a product on **example.com** it redirects them to **newdomain.com** which is masked by **pay.example.com**

Comment: The `R` flag will always implement an external redirection, which clearly is _not_ what you want. Actually you do not want a redirection at all, but either an _internal rewrite_ or a proxy (`P` flag). The proxy approach can work, but it comes with a huge performance disadvantage (each request has to be translated into a second, internal request, that is quite an overhead). Consider if you really can't use a simple internal rewrite to achieve whatever you are looking for.

Comment: You should revise your question (there is an "edit" link below it) to add information about the layout of your http hosts. You only say they are served from the same system. But do they share a common host definition, so are aliases or are they separate host? Is it a shared `DOCUMENT_ROOT` or separate ones?

Comment: @arkascha They are separate document roots, I will edit the question. Thanks.